# does ThreadPool core threads are always live once created

Tags: java, threadpool

Does java guarantee that the corepool threads will always remain active in ThreadPoolExecutor?

I ran my test code multiple times but it seems it does not guaranteed.

I tried with allowCoreThreadTimeOut=true and allowCoreThreadTimeOut = false. However, there was no change in behavior.

Here is my test code. Please try with two different values of noOfTaskToRun 1 and 4.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int noOfTaskToRun = 1;
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(2, 4, 2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());
    executor.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(false);
    List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();

    for(int i = 0; i<noOfTaskToRun ; i++)
        threads.add(new Thread("thread" + i) {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    for (Thread thread : threads) {
        executor.execute(thread);
    }

    System.out.println("Before executor.getActiveCount(): "+ executor.getActiveCount());

    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("After executor.getActiveCount(): "+ executor.getActiveCount());
}
```

I modified the keepAliveTime to 2000. Even now the threads are timing out.

Comment: What did your test exactly look like? Can we have some code, please?

Comment: You have set the timeout to be 30 seconds, but you only wait for 5 seconds.  I suggest you wait longer than the timeout, to see something happen then the timeout occurs.

Comment: I modified the timeout. I am still getting random results.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually not 100% sure, but `getActiveCount()` is not what you think, I think. 
The Docs say: "Returns the approximate number of threads that are actively executing tasks." So, my guess would be that idle threads are not included in that number but can still be alive.
What you probably want is `getPoolSize()`: "Returns the current number of threads in the pool."

Addition: If your Tasks sleep 5 secs and you give all of them a 5 sec timeout, it will be pretty random how many of them will have finished after the timeout ...

Comment: Thanks Fildor. I think I found out the reason. I checked the active threads from visualVM also and found out that the results are not different.

Comment: I will do some more experiment before concluding it. I do agree with you that getActiveCount does not give actual number of active threads.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding it will not. I saw the code(JDK 6) also and it seems that if the number of threads is less than corepoolthreads in the lifetime of executor than it guarantees but once the limit is crossed there is no guarantee that the core threads will remain alive.

I tried to ran with allowCoreThreadTimeOut = false. Even then the threads died if the number of threads crosses the coreThreadPoolSize. However, if the number of threads remain less than the coreThreadPoolSize then they remained alive.

I think the reason lies in these two methods of ThreadPoolExecutor class. From workerCanExit does check for the value of coreThreadPoolSize or allowCoreThreadTimeOut when the queue is empty and this is the reason the threads are getting timed out.

```
    Runnable getTask() {
    for (;;) {
        try {
            int state = runState;
            if (state > SHUTDOWN)
                return null;
            Runnable r;
            if (state == SHUTDOWN)  // Help drain queue
                r = workQueue.poll();
            else if (poolSize > corePoolSize || allowCoreThreadTimeOut)
                r = workQueue.poll(keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
            else
                r = workQueue.take();
            if (r != null)
                return r;
            if (workerCanExit()) {
                if (runState >= SHUTDOWN) // Wake up others
                    interruptIdleWorkers();
                return null;
            }
            // Else retry
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            // On interruption, re-check runState
        }
    }
}

    private boolean workerCanExit() {
    final ReentrantLock mainLock = this.mainLock;
    mainLock.lock();
    boolean canExit;
    try {
        canExit = runState >= STOP ||
            workQueue.isEmpty() ||
            (allowCoreThreadTimeOut &&
             poolSize > Math.max(1, corePoolSize));
    } finally {
        mainLock.unlock();
    }
    return canExit;
}
```

Comment: What do you think is a "corepoolthread"? If we define corePoolThreads as 10 and we have during runtime a peak of , let's say 20 Threads in the pool, then after they are idle again and all timeouts hit, there should be 10 Threads in the pool waiting for action. (With allowCoreThreatimeout set to false, of course) At least I thought so ...

Comment: If during the lifetime of executor number of active threads was greater than the coreThreadPoolSize then all of them were dead after the completion. This was not the case when the number of active threads were always less than the coreThreadPoolSize.

Comment: Can you give us the implementation, you used, so we can reproduce this?

Comment: See my answer @Braj. I think, you are looking at the wrong value.

Answer (score 0):

No it does not guarantee that.  For instance, the javadoc for [one of the constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#ThreadPoolExecutor%28int,%20int,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,%20java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue%29) says:

> "`corePoolSize` - the number of threads to keep in the pool, even if they are idle, unless `allowCoreThreadTimeOut` is set"

The obvious implication is that if you call [`allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#allowCoreThreadTimeOut%28boolean%29), then even core pool threads can timeout.

Comment: As per my understanding the ThreadPool does not honor allowCoreThreadTimeOut in JDK6. I am working on JDK6 only and have not checked other version of java

Comment: Even if that is true, the behaviour is not guaranteed.  That behaviour is an implementation artefact of Java 6 ... arguably a *bug*.  Writing your code to depend on a bug is a bad idea.

Comment: Besides, my reading of the Java 6 code for `ThreadPoolExecutor` is that `allowCoreThreadTimeOut` is honoured.  On what do you base your assertion that it is not honoured?

Comment: if you see my answer I have mentioned about the method workerCanExit() from ThreadPoolExecutor class. This method has condition workQueue.isEmpty() to check whether the thread can be closed. So, if this condition is true then it does not care about any other condition and returns true which in turn closes the worker thread.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your previous comment. I agree with you that I should not depend on a bug. I brought it to this forum just to understand what is happening there? I was setting this parameter allowCoreThreadTimeOut to false and even then the threads were timing out. That lead to this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

According to ThreadPoolExecutor docs core threads will stay in the pool, even if they are idle unless allowCoreThreadTimeOut flag is set.

Another sitiation when a core thread dies is when an exception is thrown during a task execution. In this case this thread will be replaced with a new one.

Comment: I tried with allowCoreThreadTimeOut = false. Even then the threads were timing out.

Comment: try Executors.fixedThreadPool(n) then run an empty task, it will never time out